# Check if service is installed

Tags: service, chef-infra

How can I check if a service is installed on the node (debian and cent os/amazon)?

I want to stop and disable the service if it is installed. If the services doesn´t exist I´m getting an exception at service stopping:
*Chef::Exceptions::Service: /etc/init.d/service does not exist!*

Best regards
André

Comment: You may a guard in your service resource with `only_if { File.exist?("/etc/init.d/service")`

Comment: Tensibai, I can't upvote you if you don't put it in an answer :(

Comment: @TejayCardon Answer done, with a better explanation on different ways

Answer (score 5):

One solution would be to add a [guard](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#guards) in your service resource:

```
service "my_service" do
  action :stop,:disable
  only_if { File.exist?("/etc/init.d/my_service") }
end
```

another one would be to guard the definition of the resource itself:
Disclaimer: this is untested code for this example.

```
service "my_service" do 
  action :stop,:disable
end.if File.exist?("/etc/init.d/my_service")
```

and a last one more intuitive

```
if File.exist?("/etc/init.d/my_service")
  service "my_service" do 
      action :stop,:disable
  end
end
```

the main difference between the first example and the others is that the first one will add a resource to the collection at compile time anyway where the other will only if the file exist so you avoid a new object for this service if it's not there.

Precision, the two last solution have a little drawback, if another recipe install the service they won't see it at first time because when the recipe is compiled the file is not there, so you may end up with the service running until the next run of chef.

Answer (score 1):

use this for check

```
only_if { ::File.exist?("/etc/init.d/my_service") }
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand and modernize the existing answers: If you're using systemd you can still check the files in a guard, but they'll be in a slightly different location.

You'd want to check for the existence of a file named "servicename.service" (ex. telnet.service, named.service, etc.) in /usr/lib/systemd/system

Add an only_if statement to the resource and you're golden!

Example:

```
service "service_name" do
  action :stop
  only_if { File.exist?("/usr/lib/systemd/system/service_name.service") }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget:  Systemd changes the world, including your service specification location. It's no longer a predictable filename in only one spot, but should exist somewhere under /usr/lib/systemd.  If your system is inflicted with systemd and your File.exist?() check isn't working, make sure you're looking in the right new spot.

Comment: What about `shell_out("systemctl is-active #{service_name} --quiet").exitstatus == 0` [source](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/provider/service/systemd.rb#L164)

Comment: forking a shell to invoke a command - no doubt to open a few more and then we're the Duggars - isn't just bad coding, and ugly as can be, it's been linked to security issues in a number of different projects.

Systemd has grown, blob-like, and consumed nfs, cron and probably pam or limits.d next.  Maybe they have a simple location for scipts, if it's not too boring?